# Writing chebyshev inequality for a random variable

Tags: probability

Let the random variable varialbe $X=X(n)$ have $E(X)=u$ $u \in R$

AND $E(X^2)<\infty$ such that $VAR(X)=\sigma^2/n$ where $\sigma^2>0$ is a fixed positive number and $n>=1$ is some intger number.

Write chebyshev inequality for $P(|X-u|>=t)$ for an arbitrary $t>0$

So I am not sure how to do this one. We know that the standard deviation sigma is $
\sigma=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt(n)}$ and then chebyshey inequality says $P(|X-u|<k*\sigma)<=\frac{1}{k^2}$ but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any random variable with $\mathbb{E}[Z^2]< \infty$ chebyshev's inequality states that
$$\mathbb{P}(|Z-\mathbb{E}[Z]| > t) \leq \frac{Var(Z)}{t^2},$$
for any $t>0$. Thus for a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,...$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = u$ for all $n$ and $Var(X_n) = \sigma^2/n$, chebyshevs inequality gives that
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n - u| > t) \leq \frac{Var(X_n)}{t^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{nt^2}.$$